# ClearCase: How to find files not labelled with "LB" on CURRENT Version selected by config spec

Tags: version-control, find, clearcase, cleartool

For example, the current config spec is "element * /main/LATEST".
There is a file "A.txt", its current version is 3 and a label named "LB" was applied on its version 2 before.

I want a command to query all files which do not have the label "LB" on its current version.

Obviously, file "A.txt" should meet the query.

How to write the clearcase command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[That command](http://www.samecs.com/commands/cleartool%20commands/find/find.htm#_Toc193967920) could help you:

```
cleartool find . -type f -version "version(/main/LATEST) && !lbtype(LB)" -print
```

That will print all the versions (files here) at `/main/LATEST` that haven't yet the '`LB`' label.

Comment: Still works in 2019 ;-). Sometimes progress is .... slow. Btw, I suppose if one wants to check the respective file versions selected in the given view (i.e., not always /main/<specific_version>) MrTiZ' answer below is correct?

Comment: @Peter Yes, the answer below is not restricted to the main branch

Answer (score 6):

```
cleartool find /your/path -cview -version "! lbtype(LB)" -print
```

- `-cview` and `-version` restrict find to the versions of the current view
- `-version "! lbtype(LB)"` find versions without `LB`

Comment: This answer is much better since it works whichever the configspec.