# List of UnLabelled files in Clear case reporting wizard

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

Using clear case reporting wizard how could i retreive the list of unlabelled files in a branch from a specific date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need first a view configured to select element on that specific date: use a [time-based selection rule config spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370008/6309):

```
element /myPath/... /main/{!created_since(16-Sep-2009)}
element /myPath/... /main/LATEST
```

I would recommend a dynamic view for that, as you can easily tweak said config spec until you see the versions you want, and quickly refresh the view after each config spec modification.

Once the view is properly set, you can use:

- a [simple find query to list all version *not* labelled with a specific label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3334547/6309)
- or try the ClearCase reporting wizard, after having to [select first the appropriate script](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21128614) (which are in `C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\reports\scripts`, like mentioned [in this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014080216)).
  I suspect it is easy to configure those scripts to report all labelled versions, I don't know if you can report the "negative" form (all non-labelled version for a given label).